# How to remove recursively a file from git local?

Tags: git, git-rm

I have `commit` by mistake before setting the `.gitignore`.

Now I am cleaning up my repository.

I use :

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged fileToBeUntracked
```

and then I remove them from repository , I mean I want to remove from the index but keep the files:

```
git rm -r --cached fileToBeRemoved
```

The problem is I have , let's say `.classpath` present in multiple folders. I get the following error :

```
fatal: pathspec '.classpath' did not match any files
```

Is there a combination with `grep` that allow me to remove all the `.classpath` from all folders, knowing that I used the option `-r` with remove command but It didn't work.

Comment: For delete the files '.classpath' the command is `git rm -r --cached **/.classpath`

Answer (score 0):

You could use git-filter-branch to run a command on every commit:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'find . -name .classpath -delete' HEAD
```

In general, have a look at [Rewriting History](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) from the git website.

Comment: not working sorry but it is a good start for me ... thank you